# How to enable multiple users on Google Talk for Android 2.3.4?

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, updates, google-talk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use Google Talk with multiple accounts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8877/use-google-talk-with-multiple-accounts)

I always use two Google accounts. One for personal use, and the other for professional-related things. On my phone, I have Android 2.3.4 installed (not rooted). I heard that multiple users have been enabled for Honeycomb's Google Talk app. I need that same feature for my phone but I can't seem to find the latest Google Talk app on the Play Store in order for me to update the one that came with my phone. What should I do?

**Note:** Google Talk's I need the voice calling feature as well.

Comment: You've had a few questions closed as duplicates.  If you aren't, please make sure you search before posting!  If you are, I apologize for how hard it is to find things here sometimes :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Talk is not one of the apps that Google updates via the Play Store. Unfortunately pre-honeycomb Gtalk can only handle one user; the main account of the phone.
Your only option is to use a third-party IM client.

Comment: I believe I can't utilize Google Talk's voice call capabilities if I use 3rd parties right?

Comment: @Shedo No you can't. I only found one app that claims to support it, but that hasn't been updated in a year.